# How to format year of jQueryUI datepicker calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar, format, jquery-ui-datepicker

I can format month which is on the top of calendar by monthNames option.
But I don't know how to format year.

I want to covert "June 2011" in the following demo calendar to like "June 2011y".
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: in japanese, "June 26, 2011" is called "2011nen 6gatsu 26nichi".
nen, gatsu, and nichi actually are not alphabets but chinese characters.
the meanings are year, month, day.
y of 2011y means year.
i use "y" because i thought people here dont know japanese language.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but I don't know Japanese :)  I would think, though, that you wouldn't need something for a year, since it's 4-digit and months/days could never be four digit.  I could see that being used for shorthand, like `11nen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/VPaRM/)

In the [jQueryUI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearSuffix):

- Initialize a datepicker with the yearSuffix option specified:

  ```
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ yearSuffix: 'CE' });
  ```
- Get or set the yearSuffix option, after init:

  ```
  //getter
  var yearSuffix = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "yearSuffix" );

  //setter
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "yearSuffix", 'CE' );
  ```

Comment: thank you very much. that is exactly what i want to know. i overlooked the option on the document.

Comment: no prob, easy to do, especially when there's so much of it.  However, if you wanted to add a prefix, or really do some year modification, you may have to use the dateformat, like David suggested, or use a callback to modify the generated string.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Code examples

```
Initialize a datepicker with the dateFormat option specified.
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
Get or set the dateFormat option, after init.
//getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showMonthAfterYear: true,
    yearSuffix: "Year", //this is what you are looking for
}

});
```